# Can't filter with filter_groups property in rapier2d and bevy

Tags: rust, bevy, rapier-2d

I'm trying to use the `filter_groups` property to filter some obstacles but I don't know why nothing is filtered:

```
fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut atlases: ResMut<Assets<TextureAtlas>>,
    server: Res<AssetServer>,
) {
    let image_handle: Handle<Image> = server.load("spritesheets/spritesheet_Mario.png");
    let texture_atlas = TextureAtlas::from_grid(
        image_handle,
        Vec2::new(SPRITE_MARIO_WIDTH, SPRITE_MARIO_HEIGHT),
        SPRITESHEET_COLS,
        SPRITESHEET_ROWS,
        Option::from(Vec2::new(SPRITE_PADDING_X, SPRITE_PADDING_Y)),
        Option::from(Vec2::new(SPRITE_OFFSET_X, SPRITE_OFFSET_Y)),
    );
    let atlas_handle = atlases.add(texture_atlas);

    commands
        .spawn(SpriteSheetBundle {
            sprite: TextureAtlasSprite::new(SPRITE_IDX_STAND),
            texture_atlas: atlas_handle,
            transform: Transform {
                scale: Vec3::new(
                    SPRITE_RENDER_WIDTH / SPRITE_MARIO_WIDTH,
                    SPRITE_RENDER_HEIGHT / SPRITE_MARIO_HEIGHT,
                    1.0,
                ),
                translation: Vec3::new(WINDOW_LEFT_X + 300.0, WINDOW_BOTTOM_Y + 300.0, 0.0),
                ..Default::default()
            },
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .insert(RigidBody::KinematicPositionBased)
        .insert(Collider::cuboid(
            SPRITE_MARIO_WIDTH / 2.0,
            SPRITE_MARIO_HEIGHT / 2.0,
        ))
        .insert(KinematicCharacterController{
            filter_groups: Option::from(CollisionGroups::new(
            Group::GROUP_1,
            Group::ALL, // Even if I try to filter ALL
            )),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .insert(Direction::Right)
        .insert(ActiveEvents::COLLISION_EVENTS)
        .insert(ActiveHooks::MODIFY_SOLVER_CONTACTS);
}
```

with `filter_flags: QueryFilterFlags::all()` it works but not when I try to use `filter_groups`.

I have to use `filter_groups` instead of `filter_flags` because I want to filter SOME of Fixed obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

OK the second parameter here is a `whitelist`:

```
.insert(KinematicCharacterController{
            filter_groups: Option::from(CollisionGroups::new(
            Group::GROUP_1,
            Group::ALL, // By default if we dont put nothing it's ALL
            )),
            ..Default::default()
        })
```

So here for example will interact with every obstacles.

We can put Group::NONE and the `entity` will NOT interact with any colliders:

```
.insert(KinematicCharacterController{
            filter_groups: Option::from(CollisionGroups::new(
            Group::GROUP_1,
            Group::NONE, // Changes here
            )),
            ..Default::default()
        })
```

So if we want to exclude a group to interact with an entity we can do it like this:

```
.insert(KinematicCharacterController{
            filter_groups: Option::from(CollisionGroups::new(
            Group::GROUP_1,
            Group::ALL - Group::GROUP_2,
            )),
            ..Default::default()
        })
```